# How to display web page properly on mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a table and an image, on pc It works fine, they are next to each other, but on mobile, the image should be under the table, but it either overlays the table or stays next to it. How can I fix this? I have made the table with bootstrap 4, which is required. I tried fixing the position of the table, but that overlays the image on top of the table, when I remove the fixing, they stay on the same row and you have to scroll left or right.

HTML:

```
<div id="bottom_row" class="container-fluid text-white pt-5 position-absolute">
        <h2 class="font-weight-bold">DONNEES DE MARCHE</h2>
        
        <table class="table text-white font-weight-bold  w-50 " id="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info border-3" scope="">COURS</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info border-3">38,40</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info border-3">DATE</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info border-3">38,40</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-bottom border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-bottom border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-bottom border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-bottom border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        


    </div>
    <div id="graph" class="">
    <img id="graph_img" src="graph.png" class="">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: rgb(38, 68, 105); 
 }
#top_row h3{

color: rgb(71, 147, 176);
float: left;
}
#top_row h2{

padding-left: 20%;
float: center;

}
#top_row h5{

float: right;

}
#top_row{
clear: both;

}

}
#bottom_row{
clear: both;
}

#graph_img{

padding-left: 55%;
height: 400px;

}

#graph{
padding-top: 80px; 
}

table{
font-size: 18px;
margin: 0;

}
img{
width: 100%;
}


.border-3{
border-width:3px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: rgb(38, 68, 105); 
 }
#top_row h3{

color: rgb(71, 147, 176);
float: left;
}
#top_row h2{

padding-left: 20%;
float: center;

}
#top_row h5{

float: right;

}
#top_row{
clear: both;

}

}
#bottom_row{
clear: both;
}

#graph_img{

height: 200px;
width: 50%;
position: center;
text-align: center;

}

#graph{
text-align: center;
}

table{
font-size: 18px;
margin: 0;

}
img{
width: 100%;
}


.border-3{
border-width:3px !important;
}
    </style>
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="bottom_row" class="container-fluid text-white pt-5 position-absolute">
        <h2 class="font-weight-bold">DONNEES DE MARCHE</h2>
        
        <table class="table text-white font-weight-bold  w-50 " id="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info border-3" scope="">COURS</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info border-3">38,40</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info border-3">DATE</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info border-3">38,40</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="border-top border-bottom border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-bottom border-info">XX,XX</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-bottom border-info">LOREM IPSUM</td>
                    <td class="border-top border-bottom border-info">XX,XX</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
    <div id="graph" class=""><img id="graph_img" src="graph.png" class=""></div>
```

I have added the text-align property into the image style as well as the height to make it responsive and position into the code.